# 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'. Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-null-safety

I am learning flutter and I am still trying to understand Null safety... i am actually having some troubles.

here is my code

```
     static User fromSnap(DocumentSnapshot snap) {
    var snapshot =
        snap.data() != null ? snap.data() as Map<String, dynamic> : {};

    return User(
      username: snapshot["username"],
      uid: snapshot["uid"],
      email: snapshot["email"],
      photoUrl: snapshot["photoUrl"],
      bio: snapshot["bio"],
      followers: snapshot["followers"],
      following: snapshot["following"],
    );
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "username": username,
        "uid": uid,
        "email": email,
        "photoUrl": photoUrl,
        "bio": bio,
        "followers": followers,
        "following": following,
      };
  }
```

but the error is coming from here:

> username: snapshot["username"],
> _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String')

Can you please help me to understand this?

Comment: As a wild guess, I'd say your JSON does not actually *have* a "username". If it does, please provide a [mcve] with data.

Answer (score 0):

Even though you make sure that `snapshot` is not null, it still can be that `snapshot["username"]` is null. One way to solve it is to provide a default value in case it is, for example the empty string, like

```
username: snapshot["username"] ?? '',
```

Another way is to make the `username` variable inside `User` nullable, although that might requires you to refactor many more parts of your code so it can deal with `User` objects with a `null` as name